# Sci-fi horror movie that streamed around the same time as The Cloverfield Paradox

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I watched parts of this movie and thought I was watching *The Cloverfield Paradox*. It wasn't until a couple months ago that I actually watched *TCP* and I've been looking for this other movie since then.

The movie takes place inside a spaceship. It seems they encounter some portal to another dimension or something like this. I remember an arm being reconstructed with some unknown technology (yeah, *TCP* also has an "arm scene"). This was at the beginning of the movie. Later on, we see one (some?) member of the crew acting strange... I remember a big guy wearing white (seems like people call him the butcher or something) getting like, possessed, and then attacking some other crew members.

The last thing I remember was that, at the end of the movie a guy was speaking to a being from another dimension or something; they were on a really big ship in a really chaotic location.

This movie has some similarities to *Event Horizon* and *Pandorum*.

I'm sorry I don't have more details. It was really late and I kept falling asleep during the movie. I really want to properly watch it now but I can't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds to me like [Nightflyers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightflyers_(TV_series)) - not a movie but a Syfy/Netflix show first shown in 2018.

It does involve a character with some implant in their arm which they attempt to remove, and a big guy (Angus Sampson, though not necessarily in white) running around Jack Torrance style.

Comment: The "butcher" scene was from Nightflyers indeed. The ending scene wasn't. It must be from another movie or series I watched around that time. My ADHD likes to mix my memories and play tricks on me.